# What's the point of the unit circle what does this buy me?

Tags: trigonometry

Hi I am wondering what the point of the unit circle is.

For example since the radius is $1$ the the coordinates of $P(x,y)$ are $(\cos(t), \sin(t))$, but this is not a general rule since for radius's longer than $1$, say $r$, it is $(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))$.

What do I get out of this, I can use right angles and reference angles and work stuff out. What am I missing?

Blair

Comment: It saves a lot of effort if one does not have to care about the radius

Answer (score 0):

The unit circle provides the definition of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ for $t$ not in the interval $(0, \pi/2)$.

Comment: How so? What about $\sin(\theta) := \sin(\theta \mod{2\pi})$, or a definition with power series, or one with the scalar product of unit vectors? This seems to assume the definition with right triangles, though there are many others...

Comment: Yes, it's assuming the definition with right triangles, because that's the right definition; it's the definition that motivates $\sin$ and $\cos$ in the first place. I'm not actually sure what you mean by "one with the scalar product of unit vectors"?

Comment: I mean $v \cdot w = \|v\| \|w\| \cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $v$ and $w$, which can be taken as the definition of $\cos(\theta)$. The dot product of two vectors is also called scalar product. My point is that you don't *need* the unit circle to extend the definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Sure, for $\theta \in [0, \pi]$. And my point is that the unit circle is the best definition, pedagogically speaking. I think that's a pretty good point to make in the context of this question.